# Views field rearrange

Tags: views, entities

I am using [Field group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module for creating fieldset in content type.

[image: Field Group module snapshot]

Can I have similar features while **rearranging the fields** selected in [**views**](https://drupal.org/project/views).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using module [Field group views](https://drupal.org/project/field_group_views)

Project page says

> Provides a view format for Field group.
>
> In other words, a field group can be displayed using a view. One
>   possible usecase would be to generate a table using fields as columns.

Comment: I tried this module, it promises to do that, but I am not able to select the "field group" in my view field.